# How to make local xampp accessible by other network for my Android App

Tags: android-studio, xampp

I have an android app made in android studio that uses xampp as a server and database. It can only be accessed through the same network. How do I make it accessible through another network to make my app work on other networks? Do I need my own domain and change my android project's URLs to my domain? or must I do it in another way?